# AngularJs: How to upload images to another service?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am building a MEAN application (Angular + node + Express + Mongo).
In this app there are users who can upload a limited amount of pictures (lets say 5).
I really want to avoird storing too many data on my server.

So I am looking for a module that let users upload the images to a service such as picasa, imageshack... The service should be transparent to the user. 
When it's done, I save the picture URL in my DB and so I can retrieve it and display pictures easily.

Do you know such module / tutorial to do that? Does it even exists?

I have been looking but it seems to not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a service doing it:
http://cloudinary.com/

With a nodejs integration:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration

It seems perfect (free up to 500 MO and 50.000 pictures, far enough for my needs).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have a file upload service with AngularJS as the front end and NodeJS as the backend is to use the jQuery File Upload for use with AngularJS, which can be found [here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html).

It makes use of a directive that you can use to upload your file.

You need to specify a route to which the uploaded file should be POST'ed to.

In this route handle, that is in you Node.js server, you can then post it to the external image hosting servers. This is something that you can write on your own or you can use the node.js modules for the respective hosts (if they exist).

Comment: Yes I could do that. But I was more looking for a component that's already made. Something that may work as follow (for example): a link to a distant app (picasa or something where my app is registered) that will open a popup/iframe in wich the user can upload pictures. At the end of the process I can retrieve the pictures URLs and saved in my DB. Maybe it doesn't exists (too bad). Upload/displaying image is a common feature, I would like to avoid doing it. For example, in my app, I use 3rd party logging system (via FB, google..). It's works perfectly, and I almost didn't code anything... ;)